# several grepl with upper and lower

Tags: r, filter, stringr, uppercase, grepl

I have the following data.frame:
[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtbUy.jpg)

I'm using `dplyr` and `stringr`, and I want to filter the column `Nombre` in the following way: retain all rows that contain "regimen" or "promocion" or "REGIMEN" or "PROMOCION", i.e., both in uppercase and lowercase. I tried:

```
str_view(df$Nombre, regex("regimen|promocion", ignore_case=T))
```

but in that case, it only retains the first word (regimen) both in upper and lower case. If I remove ignore_case=T, it finds both "regimen" and "promocion" but case sensitive, i.e., only lowercase.

Of course, this is an example, I need to filter lots of words, not just "regimen" and "promocion", that's why I don't filter each word separately.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Questions should be reproducible. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values

Comment: Hi there. I was wondering whether my answer helped you solve your problem. It'd be nice if you let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data seems to be in Spanish, I would use a regexp a bit more sofisticated (able to catch accents too).

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(
  N = c(100, 12345, 666, 888),
  Nombre = c("RÉGIMEN", "promoción", "ley", "otro regimen")
)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Nombre, regex("r\\wgimen|promoci\\wn", ignore_case = TRUE)))
#>       N       Nombre
#> 1   100      RÉGIMEN
#> 2 12345    promoción
#> 3   888 otro regimen
```

Comment: This solution is nice. But it's quite close to my solution (see below); the only differences are the use of `\\w` for accented chars and `str_detect`. You do not however acknowledge the fact that you are re-using my data and you also forgot to mention that `str_dtect`is part of the `stringr` package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` from `dplyr` as well as `grepl` from `base R` and `(?i)`to make the pattern matching case-insensitive:

```
library(dyplr)
df %>%
  filter(grepl("(?i)regimen|promocion", Nombre))
      N       Nombre
1   100      Regimen
2 12345    promocion
3   888 otro regimen
```

Alternatively, you can simply subset the dataframe using the same pattern:

```
df[grepl("(?i)regimen|promocion", df$Nombre),]
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  N = c(100, 12345, 666, 888),
  Nombre = c("Regimen", "promocion", "ley", "otro regimen")
)
```

Comment: You had no accents in your post. Please note that the solution I posted obviously also works with accented words, such as `RÉGIMEN", "promoción`; all you need to do is adapt the pattern. Do feel free to accept @crestor's answer but also consider upvoting my answer

Comment: I want to upvote your answer but the following message appears: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.